# JSON parsing for a particular element

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-el

Below xpath expression looks for AccountNo  element anywhere in whole xml document.

    `#[xpath3('//AccountNo').text]`

I am after similar expression to get AccountNo from a json request if present anywhere.

Below are example xml request containing AccountNo.

```
    <Account>
   <AccountName>John</AccountName>
   <AccountNo>4234324</AccountNo>
</Account>

<Order>
<OrderId>34234242</OrderId>
<ServiceOrder>
    <AccountNo>231232</AccountNo>
    <ServiceOrderId>54654698787</ServiceOrderId>
</ServiceOrder>
<ServiceOrder>
    <AccountNo>231232</AccountNo>
    <ServiceOrderId>78979879797</ServiceOrderId>
</ServiceOrder>
</Order>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Can you show us the whole xml document?

Comment: https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/json-module-reference

Check this out.

Comment: Please find above two example xml requests

Answer (score 0):

To get the value from a JSON payload element in Mule flow you first need to convert the json payload to object as below.

```
<json:json-to-object-transformer returnClass="java.lang.Object" doc:name="JSON to Object"/>
```

Then fetch the json payload element as below. In below code I am fetching the value of RecordId from json payload.

```
<set-variable variableName="RecordID" value="#[payload.DocProcessingMessage.UploadEfnolDocument.RecordId]" doc:name="Variable_RecordID"/>
```

Once you are done, Convert the payload back to JSON for further processing.

```
  <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert xml payload to Json then process the payload using transformer

```
<json:xml-to-json-transformer doc:name="XML to JSON" mimeType="application/json"/>
<set-payload value="{ &quot;AccountNo&quot;: &quot;#[json:Account:AccountNo]&quot;}" mimeType="application/json" doc:name="payload"/>
```